# How to publish a publication in ServiceNow using the rest api

Tags: rest, servicenow

I have publications in my ServiceNow instance.  In the UI, I can send a publication to the users that subscribe to it.  I need to automate this.  How would I accomplish sending the publication using the ServiceNow rest api?

I'm farther.  Add a record to the table sn_publications_publication using "stage:Author".  Then update the record using "stage:Review".
I see my publication in the second step in the UI.  But no email is sent.  If I do this using only the UI, the email goes out.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create the publication

POST: https://servicenow-instance/api/now/table/sn_publications_publication

Request body:
{"short_description":"test publication","recipient_lists":"12345","content_type":"html","percentage":"100","skip_notifications":"false","include_attach_links":"false","text":"test publication email","error_state":"false","expiry_date":"2022-06-14 23:02:33","recurrence":"false","stage":"Author","category":"Information","publish_date":"2022-06-14 22:02:33"}

2. Put the publication in review

PUT: https://servicenow-instance/api/now/table/sn_publications_publication/<sys_id>

Request body:
{"stage":"Review"}

3. View the stage of the publication using REST, it is now "ready_to_publish".  In that state, the email will go out at the publish date.